# Google maps with geocoding

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, maps, google-geocoder

Hi I am using google map javascript api v3

here is my code to draw polylines.

```
for(var i=0; i < addressArr.length; i++){
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressArr[i]}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        point = results[0].geometry.location;
        place.push(results[0].address_components[1].long_name);

        flightPlanCoordinates.push(point);
        if(flightPlanCoordinates.length == addressArr.length){
        flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({path: flightPlanCoordinates,strokeColor: "#FF0000",strokeOpacity: 0.50,strokeWeight: 2 });
        flightPath.setMap(map);
        }
```

addressArr is an Array of addresses

The problem is in my flightPlanCoordinates ,they are not in the order in which i am passing the addressArr from the for loop.
suppose i am passing addressArr=[1,2,3,4] the my flightPlanCoordinates becomes [2,3,1,4].
Can any suggest what is happening.

Comment: Gmaps4rails also displays polylines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply because inside of loop you make asyncronous call(geocoder.geocode) which takes different ammount of time to accomplish. So suggest that it takes 1 second to geocode second element in array and 3 seconds to geocode first element. Then obviously the second element's callback function will be called before the first and thus will push it into flightPlanCoordinates on first position.

Just call sort() method on the array inside of second if statement in your code to solve the issue.

UPDATE:

```
var i = 0;
function geocode(){
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': addressArr[i]
    },
    function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            point = results[0].geometry.location;
            place.push(results[0].address_components[1].long_name);
            flightPlanCoordinates.push(point);
            i++;
            if(addressArr[i] != null)
                geocode();

            if (flightPlanCoordinates.length == addressArr.length) {
                flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.50,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                });
                flightPath.setMap(map);
            }
        }
    }
}
geocode();
```

Comment: You are right this is the issue but sorting doesn't solve the problem.The routes are not showing properly because my array contains latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: can i make the geocode call wait untill it returns the first response.

Comment: when i added an alert inside the loop it worked but this can't be the solution.

Comment: instead of looping through elements you could call geocode function recursively and make every new geocode call only in a callback function of previous call. see my code snippet in updated answer. i'm not sure if it runs right away as i didn't have chance to run this code, but i hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

No too sure why its returning the values like that but you could just sort the array and that will resolve your problem. flightPlanCoordinates.sort();